Access Aruba S5300 Web GUI with Modern Firefox Browser
Context: We have multiple Aruba S5300 switches on the networks we maintain. After a "factory reset," we usually go to the web GUI at https://172.16.0.254 to do the initial configuration.
A few weeks ago, we reset an Aruba switch and when we tried to access the interface, we got a cipher error.
Firefox returned...
An error occurred during a connection to 172.16.0.254:4343. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s).

Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

Chromium returned...
This site can’t provide a secure connection
172.16.0.254 uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.

So obviously something related to ciphers.
So we used sslScan to enumerate the cipher suite being used on the switch. Here is the output...
PS C:\Users\owner\Downloads\sslscan-2.1.4> .\sslscan.exe 172.16.0.254:4343
Version: 2.1.4 Windows 64-bit (Mingw)
OpenSSL 3.0.14 4 Jun 2024

Connected to 172.16.0.254

Testing SSL server 172.16.0.254 on port 4343 using SNI name 172.16.0.254

  SSL/TLS Protocols:
SSLv2     disabled
SSLv3     enabled
TLSv1.0   enabled
TLSv1.1   disabled
TLSv1.2   disabled
TLSv1.3   disabled

  TLS Fallback SCSV:
Server does not support TLS Fallback SCSV

  TLS renegotiation:
Secure session renegotiation supported

  TLS Compression:
Compression disabled

  Heartbleed:
TLSv1.0 not vulnerable to heartbleed

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
Preferred TLSv1.0  112 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1.0  112 bits  DHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA          DHE 1024 bits

  SSL Certificate:
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
RSA Key Strength:    2048

Subject:  securelogin.arubanetworks.com
Altnames: DNS:securelogin.arubanetworks.com
Issuer:   GeoTrust DV SSL CA

Not valid before: May 11 01:22:10 2011 GMT
Not valid after:  Aug 11 04:40:59 2017 GMT

Obviously an expired certificate and some old protocols. With that in mind, we decided to try to use one of the enabled protocols - SSLv3 or TLSv1.0.
In Firefox, I created a new profile and modified these values...
security.tls.version.min    1
security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha   true    
security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha   true

No luck.
Then we tried this with Chromium:
"chrome.exe" --ssl-version-min=tls1 --ssl-version-max=tls1.1
Still, no luck.
Finally, we just installed Firefox ESR version 45 (yes, you read that correctly) and while it did grumble about the connection being insecure, it did load the interface.
The question...
What values need to be modified in Firefox settings to be able to access a switch that uses these old ciphers: DES-CBC3-SHA or DHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA?
And yes, we understand these are old, insecure protocols. Etc, etc.

Update: My main curiosity is whether we can access old switches with a modern, supported browser - particularly Firefox.
In our case, accessing the switches securely is a non-event. These are on a secured internal network. We would use non-secure HTTP if it was available, but it is not.
I also understand the switches are old and firmware needs an update. The particular switch that started this questions has been in inventory for years. But even with the latest offering from the vendor, it still has cipher issues like mentioned above.
And yes, I do use portable editions of older browsers. They work well for one-off situations like this. (And I understand one could argue what is the difference between using a portable app and using a different profile with security weakened - both require remembering the "different" configuration and both require using a weaken security.)
So again, my main curiosity is whether this can be done with modern browser. And if so, how.

This answer says you can use a socat intermediary. I don't know any more about this. Note, this is why it is useful to not use a gui, but the command line via unencrypted telnet or even a serial port to such devices if they are local. It is also easier to script commands to configure the device from a factory reset.

For EOL product there isn’t much choice, unless you can use HTTP on it, which is even less secure than using an old browser
On my side I have a bunch of old Firefox’s portable edition to be able to load the GUI of any older product.
I usually don’t mind for APC or such gear the fact that it’s old, but for switch it’s a sign to maybe think to replace

This problem would not exist if the firmware had been updated. Network gear is famous for every device has a different firmware version, with all being vulnerable/non-compliant. Even in the most neglected environments it's unusual to find devices that haven't been updated in 15 years...also has a SHA1-signed certificate from a public CA.
